# Python script works when executed in IDLE, but not in console

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

### Preface

System OS: Windows 10

First of, I have python in `PATH`, so that is not the problem. Other scripts work fine from the console.

---

### Purpose of the python script?

Read parameters from a `.csv` file, and fill respective annotation fields in a `.PDF`

---

When the script is executed in Python's IDLE, the output pdf file is created. However, the pdf file is not created when the script is opened from the console.

I think it must have something to do with the `Current Working Directory` and my relative paths. That's why I added the line:

```py
os.chdir(os.getcwd().replace(os.sep, '/'))
```

However, that did not seem to help.

Full Python script:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python
import os , pdfrw , csv

INPUT_CSV_PATH = 'Tested_parameters.csv'
INVOICE_TEMPLATE_PATH = 'Input_template.pdf'
INVOICE_OUTPUT_PATH = 'output_document.pdf'
ANNOT_KEY = '/Annots'
ANNOT_FIELD_KEY = '/T'
ANNOT_FIELD_NAME = '/TU'
ANNOT_VAL_KEY = '/V'
ANNOT_RECT_KEY = '/Rect'
SUBTYPE_KEY = '/Subtype'
WIDGET_SUBTYPE_KEY = '/Widget'

def write_fillable_pdf(input_pdf_path, output_pdf_path, data_dict):
    template_pdf = pdfrw.PdfReader(input_pdf_path)
    annotations = template_pdf.pages[1][ANNOT_KEY]
    for annotation in annotations:
        if annotation[SUBTYPE_KEY] == WIDGET_SUBTYPE_KEY: # '/Subtype': '/Widget'
            if annotation[ANNOT_FIELD_KEY]: # '/T'
                key = annotation[ANNOT_FIELD_KEY][1:-1]
                if key in data_dict.keys():
                    if (key[0:4] == 'check'):
                        annotation.update( pdfrw.PdfDict( V=data_dict[key], AS=data_dict[key]) )        
                    else:
                        annotation.update( pdfrw.PdfDict(AP=data_dict[key], V=data_dict[key], F=0) )
    pdfrw.PdfWriter().write(output_pdf_path, template_pdf)

def Inport_csv_to_dict(input_pdf_path):
    with open(input_pdf_path,encoding="utf-8-sig") as fh:
        rd = csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=',')
        for row in rd:
            data_dict = row
    return data_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.chdir(os.getcwd().replace(os.sep, '/'))
    data_dict = Inport_csv_to_dict(INPUT_CSV_PATH)
    write_fillable_pdf(INVOICE_TEMPLATE_PATH, INVOICE_OUTPUT_PATH, data_dict)
```

Comment: Is there any error or exception ?

Comment: Maybe the PDF is created in a place other than the one you are looking. Changing the CWD to the same directory is a no-op. It's not clear what that is intended to accomplish.

Comment: `os.getcwd` returns the current working directory, and `os.chdir` sets the current working directory, so `os.chdir(os.getcwd().replace(os.sep, '/'))` changes absolutely nothing. Changing backslash to slash here is pointless. The underlying WINAPI `SetCurrentDirectoryW` call first normalizes the path, which among other things, replaces slashes with the native backslash path separator.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this was kind of stupid from my part, but it works now.

I had the `#! /usr/bin/python` on the first line of my script. So the console run the script with python 2.

I removed the first line, and it worked as it should (with Python 3)

Comment: If you have .py scripts associated with the py.exe launcher, then change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/python3` to ensure that it executes with Python 3.